# Powershell Email attachment - "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: powershell, email, email-attachments

Here is the situation:

I want to write a script in Powershell (I've never done it before) that does the following. A file with a different name is created in a directory every 8 hours. I would like to send this via email, and the ps1 file would be started in task scheduler every 8 hours.

```
$Dated = Get-date -Uformat %y%m%d
$Excluded = "k*.doc","k*.docx"
$attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\*\* -Recurse -Include $Dated*.* -Exclude $Excluded | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
$AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName
$SMTPServer = "xxxx"
$EmailTo = "xxxx"
$EmailFrom = "xxxx"
$Body = "$AttachmentName"
$Subject = "$AttachmentName"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment.Fullname)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

I have solved this so that only the latest file is sent, but when the file is in use (opened in MS Word), I get the error "The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process".
If Word is no longer using the file, it successfully sends the attachment.

How do I rewrite the script to avoid this error and add the file?

Answer (score 0):

this solution is the simplest, but I haven't tested it. Perhaps you should check for file occupancy and terminate the word process.

```
$Dated = Get-date -Uformat %y%m%d
$Excluded = "k*.doc","k*.docx"
$attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\*\* -Recurse -Include $Dated*.* -Exclude $Excluded | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
$AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName
$SMTPServer = "xxxx"
$EmailTo = "xxxx"
$EmailFrom = "xxxx"
$Body = "$AttachmentName"
$Subject = "$AttachmentName"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment.Fullname)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");
$check = $true
do {
    try{ 
        $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
        $check = $false      
    }catch{
          write-host "file blocked"
          Wait-Event -Timeout 300 
    }
}
while($check)
```